# java random numbers

Tags: java

I need to make a program  that asks how many random numbers you want to generate. The random numbers has to be between in a range from 0 to 50.

I have something like this:

```
 import java.util.Random; 
 import javax.swing.*;
 public class Random_number { 
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int message;
     String input =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("h­ow many randoms?");
     int inputInt =Integer.parseInt(input);
     String range =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("w­hat range");
     int rangeInt = Integer.parseInt(range);
     Random rand = new Random();
     int number = 0;
     int i = 0;   
     for(i=0; i <= inputInt; i++){ 
       number =1+rand.nextInt(rangeInt); 
       System.out.println(number); 
     }
   } 
 }
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what seems to be the problem?

Comment: @DanielA.White I think the problem might be the formatting ;-)

Comment: the range 0-50 where do i have to put it in this code

Comment: Generate a random number between 0 & 1 and multiply it by 50 i.e. `(int)(Math.random()*50)`

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
Random random = new Random();
System.out.println(random.nextInt(50));
```

This will give you a pseudo random range from 0 (inclusive) to 50 (exclusive)

Comment: Having just re-read your post I'm not sure I'm actually answering your question - if not, please ignore :-)

Comment: i'm sure he's thankful for you doing his homework for him :p

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force the user to enter a range between 0 and 50 inclusive, you could try using a loop:

```
int rangeInt = -1;
while(rangeInt < 0 || rangeInt > 50) {
  String range = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What range (0-50)?");
  rangeInt = Integer.parseInt(range);
}
```

There also seems to be some problems with the `for` loop, mainly it iterates one too many times.  In addition, you should probably be doing something to handle the cases where the user input is not numeric.